# Android view distorted after animation or from background to active

Tags: android

I have a pie chart, the normal situation is this:http://pfile.cn/ls1wkc
The pie chart can be clicked to show the accounting, but after the rotating animation, it will become like this:http://pfile.cn/jvo8k7   And when from the background to the activation state will also appear this problem.My test Android device's target is 4.4.4.

Have you ever encountered a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.Only need to open the hardware acceleration or software acceleration in the pieView.

```html
this.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, paint);
```